# Win 10 ethernet connection is randomly displaying different names. Some have no internet connections

Tags: networking, connection

Windows 10, Turn on computer and have no internet.  Network is connecting to several different names.  Spanman13, connects with internet, ip 192.168.0.1.  Spanman, connects but with no internet, 192.168.1.1.  Network3, connects to internet, 192.168.0.1.  Why 3 different connections.  I have to disable the network adapter and keep abling it till I get a internet connection.  Why shouldn't this be just one connection and get it locked in?

Comment: Ethernet should not (will not) do this. What you describe is a wireless issue.

Comment: @John: Windows detects its "network names" based on other things than just SSID (e.g. including subnet prefix, advertised DNS search list, gateway MAC). It's quite possible to happen on Ethernet.

Comment: On my wired connections, here and clients, I just "Network Connected"  Of course, there is just one DHCP Server, and no Registry edits.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your network has multiple DHCP servers in it. They're all offering your computer an address and some gateway settings (of course, each one is trying to advertise itself as "the gateway") – and your computer ends up picking one offer at random.

- If you have some routers acting as Wi-Fi access points, unplug them from the main network and connect *directly* to a computer. If the computer gets an IP address, then the device is causing your problems and needs to be reconfigured.
- Open a Wireshark capture, plug in the cable, then look for "DHCP Offer" packets. Look at their source MAC addresses. Compare them with the MAC from the sticker on your main router. If it doesn't match, then it's the one causing problems.

Comment: Thank You, your a psychic, you saw through my omissions. I, did, have a second router as a WIFI service connected directly to the main router where my computer was connected.  I did not realize that my computer was connecting from main router to 2nd router and then back to the main router and out to internet.  Crazy.  But disconnected 2nd router and will check settings and put in to bridge mode.  I think that should cure my issues.  If I am wrong please advise.  Thank you, again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it does.  At different times when I turn my computer on, my Ethernet connection will be one of three different names.  Spanman, which is also my WIFI name, will also appear as my Ethernet connection with out internet connectivity.  Tonight I am connected to Network 3 and have good connectivity to internet.  This morning it was connected to Spanman 13 on the Ethernet and good internet connectivity.  I have looked at the registry and found Spanman 13 connection and Spanman and Network 3.  I have one router and it was always connecting to Spanman 13 as assigned by Microsoft, randomly.  I am cautious to edit the registry and delete two of the connections listed.  My WIFI works just fine.

Comment: When this happens I disable the Ethernet device and enable it two or three times before it will pick one of the correct names that gives me internet.